# problema com menu no firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Galera montei uma tabela onde clico com botão direito sobre ela e abra um menu. O problema e que no firefox tenho que dar 2 cliques. E ele fica fechando quando movimento o mouse.

Testei em todos os navegadores e esta tudo ok. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Vou colocar o link do jsfiddle pois fica mais fácil para testar o erro no firefox.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/q6jGr/187/)

Desde já agradeço.

```js
document.oncontextmenu = function() {
  return false;
};
sair = function(e) {
  var novo = e.toElement;

  if (!($(novo).closest('.context_menu_pai').length || $(novo).closest('#' + menu).length)) {
    $(".context_menu_pai").hide();
    menu = false;
  }

};
var menu = false;
$("tr")
  .mousedown(function(e) {

    // Define a posição do menu
    $('.context_menu_pai').css({
      "margin-left": e.clientX,
      "margin-top": e.clientY
    });

    // Exibe o menu
    if (e.button === 2) {
      menu = this.id;
      $("#menu" + this.id).show();
      $(".context_menu_pai:not(#menu" + this.id + ")").hide();
    } else {
      $(".context_menu_pai").hide();
      menu = false;
    }
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(e) {
    sair(e);
  });
$('.context_menu_pai').on('mouseout', function(e) {
  sair(e);
});
```

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
   color: #484848;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 13px;
 }
 
 .context_menu_pai {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   border-radius: 2px;
 }
 
 .context_menu {
   padding: 12px 8px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   color: #484848;
 }
 
 .context_menu:hover {
   background: #EEEEEE;
 }
 
 .text_erro {
   color: #F65314;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='context_menu_pai' id='menu1'>
  <li class='context_menu'>Editar</li>
</div>
<div class='context_menu_pai' id='menu2'>
  <li class='context_menu'>Editar</li>
  <li class='context_menu'>Acessar</li>
  <li class='context_menu'>Indicou(0)</li>
  <li class='context_menu text_erro'>Bloquear</li>
</div>
<div class='context_menu_pai' id='menu3'>
  <li class='context_menu'>Editar</li>
  <li class='context_menu'>Acessar</li>
  <li class='context_menu'>Indicou(0)</li>
  <li class='context_menu text_erro'>Bloquear</li>
</div>



<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>ID:1</td>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="2">
    <td>ID:2</td>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="3">
    <td>ID:3</td>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Update ======================================

Notei que o erro ocorro por causa deste calculo:

```
// Calculos da posição
        var pX = e.clientX - 32;
        var pY = e.clientY - 105;

        // Define a posição do menu            
        $('.context_menu_pai').css({
            "margin-left": pX,
            "margin-top": pY
        }).show();
```

Se eu usar o código assim:

```
// Define a posição do menu            
        $('.context_menu_pai').css({
            "margin-left": e.clientX,
            "margin-top": e.clientY
        }).show();
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente porem preciso do cálculo. o que esta errado com ele?

Comment: Amigo, segue o que eu estou tentando fazer no fiddle. Eu consegui manter a função editar, porém nas outras opções ainda desaparece, mas vou passar meu progresso até agora. http://jsfiddle.net/q6jGr/190/

Comment: Na definição da função sair há um erro de digitação na linha `var novo = e.toElement;`, que deveria ser `var novo = e.toElement();`. Isso parece resolver o problema aqui.

Comment: Bom Daniel so falta o menu ficar aberto.   Patético realmente resolve o problema do duplo clique, porem o menu não fecha mais ao remover o mouse dele. Vc sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @HugoBorges Ontem eu fiz apenas uma parte pra tentar te dar um empurrãozinho e por também não estar com tempo pra resolver todo. Vou tentar hoje resolver essa situação, se por acaso conseguir resolver antes que eu avise :)

Comment: Oi obrigado pela ajuda. bom com base no que vc fez eu acabei resolvendo o problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom resolvi o problema desta forma:

```
    $("body").mousedown(function (e) {

    // Verifica qual botão clicou
    if (e.button !== 2) {

        // Remove o CSS da linha selecionada
        $("tr").removeClass('context_menu_select');
        // Fecha menu
        $(".context_menu_pai").hide();
    }
     });

    $("tr").mousedown(function (e) {

    // Calculos da posição
    var pX = e.clientX - 32;
    var pY = e.clientY - 105;

    // Define a posição do menu            
    $('.context_menu_pai').css({
        "margin-left": pX,
        "margin-top": pY
    }).show();

    // Remove o CSS da linha selecionada
    $("tr").removeClass('context_menu_select');

    // Verifica qual botão clicou
    if (e.button === 2) {
        $("#menu" + this.id).show();
        $(".context_menu_pai:not(#menu" + this.id + ")").hide();

        // Remove o CSS da linha selecionada
        $("#" + this.id).removeClass('linhas');
        // Adiciona CSS na linha selecionada
        $("#" + this.id).addClass('context_menu_select');
    } else {
        // Fecha menu
        $(".context_menu_pai").hide();
    }
   });
```